# Loop in excel to traverse values in one column

Tags: excel

I have following data

```
ID  Balance  Balance_Sum  Max_Balance
1   1000      2300        1500                       
1   -200      2300        1500        
1   1500      2300        1500
```

My next column will Calculate some value if(Max_Balance < Balance_sum).
If this calculated value is > 0 then I have to select the next maximum value i.e 1000.

How can I achieve this using formula. Calculations shown above are for 1 ID. I may have thousands of such ID group.
I can not use VBA cause my file size will get too large and it takes time to load.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you want to achieve. What does "select the next maximum value" refer to? Just the entry in your Balance column? Could you provide some detail as to what "calculate some value" is? What happens when "Max_Balance >= Balance_Sum"?

Comment: @Werner : Sorry If I am not being clear. Calculate some value is for example (Balance_Sum- Max_Balance). If this value comes out to be positive then I have to calculate the value using next maximum from Balance(Excluding earlier one). And if Max_Balance>=Balance_sum then I wont take next maximum value. My calculation will end there only. Hope you are getting me

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is a part of a formula that computes a `=MAX(...)` "*from here to the end of the list*". This can be done using the =OFFSET(...) function. Let's have our list of values starting from A1, and the relative MAX starting at B1

```
B1: =MAX(OFFSET(A1;0;0;COUNT(A1:A$1000)))
```

whereby the last term of `COUNT()` is so high that it makes sure all rows are included. This works only as long as there are no blank rows in between.

You can copy this formula down and across, row 1000 is the only invariant here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub abc()
j = 2
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("a65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 2 To lastrow
Range("a" & i).Select
If Range("a" & i).Value = "East" Or Range("a" & i).Value = "west" Or Range("a" &  i).Value = "north" Or _
Range("a" & i).Value = "south" Then
GoTo cont
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("a" & j).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
j = j + 1
Sheets("sheet1").Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
cont:
Next i


'/////// column b ///////////

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 2 To lastrow
Range("b" & i).Select
If Range("b" & i).Value >= "01-01-2013" And Range("b" & i).Value <= "30-06-2013" Then
GoTo cont2
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("a" & j).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
j = j + 1
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
cont2:
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub abc()

j = 2
Sheets("sheet1").Select

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("a65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

'/// column a
ActiveSheet.Range("a3:a" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$A$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.EntireRow.Select

'    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    rownum = Selection.Row

    If rownum = 3 Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
    GoTo label1
    End If

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
 Selection.AutoFilter

'column b///////////
label1:
ActiveSheet.Range("b65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("b4:b" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$b$1:$b$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select

    Selection.EntireRow.Select

    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

    rownum = Selection.Row
    If rownum = 3 Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
    GoTo label2
    End If

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ' Selection.AutoFilter

    'column c////////////
label2:

    ActiveSheet.Range("c65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row
 ActiveSheet.Range("c4:c" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$c$1:$c$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SG Plus", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Select"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'    Selection.Copy
'    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
'    lrow = activehseet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
'    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow).Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
'    Sheets("Sheet1").Select



    rownum = Selection.Row
    If rownum = 3 Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
    GoTo label3
    End If

    Range("a4:a" & lastrow).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
'    Selection.AutoFilter


'column c again/////////////

label3:

    ActiveSheet.Range("c65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("c4:c" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$c$1:$c$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    rownum = Selection.Row
    If rownum = 3 Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
    GoTo label4
    End If

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

        Range("a4:a" & lastrow).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

    Selection.EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
'     Selection.AutoFilter

'//////////////////////////  over  /////////////////////////////

label4:

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("a" & i).Select
If Range("a" & i).Value = "MidAmerica" Or Range("a" & i).Value = "Northeast" Or Range("a" & i).Value = "Southeast" Or _
Range("a" & i).Value = "West" Then
GoTo cont
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
       Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont:
Next i


'/////// column b ///////////

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("b" & i).Select
If Range("b" & i).Value = "CA" Or Range("b" & i).Value = "AZ" Then
GoTo cont2
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont2:
Next i

'///////////column c //////////

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("c" & i).Select
If Range("c" & i).Value = "SG" Then
GoTo cont3
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont3:
Next i

'//////////column l/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("l" & i).Select
If Range("l" & i).Value <= "01/06/2014" And Range("l" & i).Value >= "01/01/2013" Then
GoTo cont4
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont4:
Next i

'//////////column m/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("m" & i).Select
If Range("m" & i).Value = "12/01" Or Range("m" & i).Value = "12/05" Then
GoTo cont5
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row


    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont5:
Next i

'//////////column q and r/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("q" & i).Select
If Range("q" & i).Value <> " " And Range("r" & i).Value <> " " And Range("u" & i).Value <> " " _
And Range("z" & i).Value <> " " And Range("aa" & i).Value <> " " And Range("ab" & i).Value <> " " _
And Range("b" & i).Value <> " " And Range("j" & i).Value <> " " Then
GoTo cont6
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont6:
Next i


End Sub
```